# Unreliable serial port

Tags: c, serial-port

I read/write (in C) to a device connected to a serial port. The initialization step succeeds, but more than half the time when I try to write to it, I get a errno=5, "Input/output error".
Is there something wrong with my setup ?

```
Set to  : cflag=0x4be, lflag=0x0, iflag=0x4, oflag=0x4
c_cc: INTR=3 QUIT=28 ERASE=127 KILL=21 EOF=1 TIME=1 START=17 STOP=19 SUSP=26 REPRINT=18 DISCARD=15 WERASE=23 LNEXT=22 
c_iflag: IGNPAR 
c_oflag: ONLCR NLDLY=NL0 CRDLY=CR0 TABDLY=TAB0 BSDLY=BS0 VTDLY=VT0 FFDLY=FF0 
c_cflag: CBAUD=B19200 CSIZE=CS8 CREAD HUPCL 
c_lflag:
```

Simplified code (error testing removed for legibility):

```
int fd=open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY );
struct termios options;
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0 ));
tcgetattr(fd, &options))
cfsetospeed(&options, Mult==2 ? B19200 : B9600);
cfsetispeed(&options, Mult==2 ? B19200 : B9600);

options.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; 
options.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOCTL | ECHONL);
options.c_cflag |= HUPCL;

options.c_oflag |= ONLCR;
options.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;

options.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
options.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

options.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | CSTOPB | CSIZE | CRTSCTS);
options.c_cflag |= CS8;

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options));

R=write(fd, Msg, strlen(Msg));
```

--> fails with errno=5, input/output error about half the time

Comment: Add some code to understand the problem.

Comment: Code added    @Swanand

Comment: You probably need to enable CLOCAL in c_cflag.  You are also going to need  CREAD in c_cflag if you plan on receiving data.

Comment: Enabled one and it worked. Enabled the other, worked also. Then removed both, still worked reliably. I don't know what the deal is but thanks !

Comment: *"Then removed both, still worked reliably."* -- That's not a stress test.  Your test probably means that those attributes are still enabled because nobody disabled them.  Try a system reboot, and then test.